# Create/Delete Telegram Bot Commands Using Python

Tags: python, command, telegram-bot

Is it possible to create/delete a new command for Telegram Bot using python? I know that BotFather can create commands using `/setcommands` but I am trying to see if I can automate creating a list of commands using Python. I am using [`pyTelegramBotAPI`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) to interact with the bot.

For example, can I batch process the following command creation without typing them in the Telegram Mobile or Desktop App?

```
command1 - Description for command 1
command2 - Description for command 2
command3 - Description for command 3
```

I would like to help the user with available commands and as soon as they type `/` I'd like Telegram to automatically show them `/command1`, `/command2`, `/command3`.

I tried the following but it does not seem to be working. None of the commands will show up after typing `/` in the app.

```
import telebot
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
tb.set_my_commands('command1')
tb.set_my_commands('command2')
tb.set_my_commands('command3')
```

Lastly, does Telegram allow to delete a command using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is pretty easy, although there is no guide for it.

`import telebot


tb = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

tb.set_my_commands([
    telebot.types.BotCommand("/start", "main menu"),
    telebot.types.BotCommand("/help", "print usage")
])`

So I suggest there is no need to delete commands, as they overwrite each time set_my_commands run.